# Vis.js JSON data to Google Spreadsheets Range

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, vis.js

I have a little issue trying to retrieve the data from the [Vis.js (here a example!)](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/saveAndLoad.html) nodes position and edges related to the id, to a Google SpreadSheets range.

Here's the code (HTML and GAS)

```js
let nodeArray = []

data.forEach(element => {
  let obj = {}
  obj.id = element[0]
  obj.label = element[1]
  obj.title = element[2]
  obj.group = element[3]
  obj.x = element[4]
  obj.y = element[5]

  nodeArray.push(obj)
  return element
})
//Logger.log(nodeArray);
return nodeArray;
}

function lineArray() {

  const data = ss.getSheetByName("Conecciones").getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1, 5).getValues();

  let edgArray = []

  data.forEach(element => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.from = element[0]
    obj.label = element[2]
    obj.dashes = element[3]
    obj.to = element[4]
    edgArray.push(obj)
    return element
  })
  //Logger.log(edgArray);
  return edgArray;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="mynetwork"></div>
  <input type="button" id="export_button" onclick="exportNetwork()" value="export">
  <p id="input_output" style="height: 680px;"></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {

      container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
      exportArea = document.getElementById('input_output');
      network = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => new vis.Network(container, {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
      }, options)).sample();

    };

    function addConnections(elem, index) {
      elem.connections = network.getConnectedNodes(index);
    }

    function exportNetwork() {
      var nodes = objectToArray(network.getPositions());
      nodes.forEach(addConnections);
      var exportValue = JSON.stringify(nodes, undefined, 2);
      exportArea.innerHTML = exportValue;
    }

    function objectToArray(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        obj[key].id = key;
        return obj[key];
      });
    }

    init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I think the problem is here, in the HTML Side

```
function addConnections(elem, index) {                                                                          
    elem.connections = network.getConnectedNodes(index);
  }

  function exportNetwork() {
    var nodes = objectToArray(network.getPositions());
    nodes.forEach(addConnections);
    var exportValue = JSON.stringify(nodes, undefined, 2);
    exportArea.innerHTML = exportValue;
  }

  function objectToArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    obj[key].id = key;
    return obj[key];
    });
  }
```

Recap:

At this point, i have problems to read the data from the google script side (its 100% tested, a it works without the "supposed problem part")

**Beforehand, thanks a lot!**

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Your example is not minimal and more importantly, your post doesn't even present a problem.

Comment: Im going to edit the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I noticed the following part. Unfortunately, `google.script.run` returns no values. So I think that when `network` is used at the function `exportNetwork()`, an error occurs at `network.getPositions()`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

  ```
    network = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => new vis.Network(container, {
      nodes: nodes,
      edges: edges
    }, options)).sample();
  ```

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

##### From:

```
function init() {

  container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  exportArea = document.getElementById('input_output');
  network = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => new vis.Network(container, {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  }, options)).sample();

};
```

##### To:

```
let network;  // Added

function init() {
  container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  exportArea = document.getElementById('input_output');
  network = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => {
      network = new vis.Network(container, {nodes: nodes, edges: edges}, options);  // Modified
  }).sample();
};
```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Unfortunately, I cannot test about your actual situation.

Comment: Man your awesome jajaj (again) you solved my problem!

Comment: I have another issue using this resulting JSON string to populate a sheets range, do you have any idea or source to achieve that? Also im going to open another answers! Thanks again!

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue, I would like to confirm when you posted it. When I could find the solution of the issue, I would like to answer to it.